# D3.js - PathTransition - Frequency and Speed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates, transition, duration

I have created a transition of an element which is based on geo-data in form of (X,Y) coordinates, obtained by a sensor with sample frequency 20HZ (= 50 milliseconds).

The code is below and everything works fine. The only thing that I cannot fix is the speed of my circle.

More specifically, the object has a constant speed during the whole transition, unlike with the real object which has speed intervals according the time.

**Is it possible in D3 path-transitions,
to have specific duration of object's sub-trasition from one point to the following one? 
And if there is no such feature do you have any idea on how I can achieve something like this?**

Thanks in advance.

```
var points = [
    [699.740051913, 552.862792064],
    [700.479711298, 552.174345089],
    [701.223572936, 551.473235667],
    [701.955862437, 550.762014322],
    [702.663479075, 550.039681113],
    [703.340310927, 549.305348384],
    [703.978797092, 548.558679344],
    [704.56828522, 547.796898661]]

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 1000)
                    .attr("height", 1000);

var path = svg.append("path")
                        .data([points])
                        .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
                                .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
                                .interpolate("lineto")
                                );

var circle = svg.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 20)   // the radius of the circle-player
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + points + ")");

var pauseValues = {
                lastT: 0,
                currentT: 0
            };      // values for pausing-resuming

circle.transition()
                    .duration(duration - (duration * pauseValues.lastT))
                    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(paths[i].node()))
                    .ease("linear")
                    .each("end", function () {
                                pauseValues = {
                                    lastT: 0,
                                    currentT: 0
                                };
                                transition();
                     });

function translateAlong(path) {
                var l = path.getTotalLength();
                return function (d, i, a) {
                    return function (t) {
                        t += pauseValues.lastT;
                        pauseValues.currentT = t;
                        return "translate(" + p.x.toFixed(0) + "," + p.y.toFixed(0) + ")";
                    };
                };
            }
```

Comment: Anyone, who can help?

Comment: You can specify a different [easing function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_ease).

Comment: I don't think that this is the case. The point is that I want Constant Speed from one point to another and not for the whole transition. Thanks by the way for your time.

Comment: Well then you simply need to change the transition times, or am I missing something?